# DataSource error: "Cannot Bind to property or Column"

Tags: c#, dataset

I'm working on a database in C# when I hit the display button I get an error:

> Error:
>   Cannot bind to the property or column LastName on the DataSource.
>   Parameter name: dataMember

Code:

```
private void Display_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.da2.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * From Customer", Program.cs);
    Program.ds2.Clear();
    Program.da2.Fill(Program.ds2);
    customerDG.DataSource = Program.ds2.Tables[0];

    Program.tblNamesBS2.DataSource = Program.ds.Tables[0];

    customerfirstname.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Program.tblNamesBS2, "FirstName"));
    customerlastname.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Program.tblNamesBS2, "LastName")); //Line Error occurs on.
}
```

Not sure what it means can anyone help, if I comment out the last two lines it will display properly.

Comment: Have you checked that LastName is correctly typed?

Comment: It means there is no column called `LastName` in the that table.

Comment: Very odd, on my SQL server manager the colum name is indeed "LastName" just like what i have typed. if i just comment out the last line it works, FirstName is correct and i spelt LastName in the same manner.

Comment: The DataSource of `Program.tblNamesBS2` is `Program.ds.Tables[0]`. But you have filled the results to another Dataset `Program.ds2`. Is this correct?

Comment: I have 2 Data sets. Program.TblNamesBS is Program.ds.Tables[0]. and i also have Program.tblNamesBS2 is Program.ds2.Tables[0]. No 2 is used for my customer form and the orginal is used for my contact Form ive used the same method.

Comment: Ahh ty Mohammad that fixed it. Should have been Program.ds2.Tables[0]

Comment: Slight prob if i click display it loads the table, but if i click display once again i get this error msg, is there a way to prevent this.. This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.
Parameter name: binding

Comment: I think you will have to clear the bindings before adding new bindings. And khan is this a windows application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it means your datatable is not finding column name LastName which is in your database..

in your case you filling your dataset with ds2..

```
 Program.da2.Fill(Program.ds2);
```

and then you are binding your datasource to 'program' like this..

```
Program.tblNamesBS2.DataSource = Program.ds.Tables[0];
```

it should like this..

```
Program.tblNamesBS2.DataSource = Program.ds2.Tables[0];
```

because below line you are looking value from Program.tblNamesBS2 which is binded to 'ds'
and that's why column are not ther in 'ds'.

```
 customerfirstname.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Program.tblNamesBS2, "FirstName"));    
  customerlastname.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Program.tblNamesBS2, "LastName"));
```

Comment: Why would this be? it can find FirstName, and LastName is spelt properly.

Answer (score 14):

You will also run into this error if you bind to a NULL object.

Comment: Create a new instance of the object and bind to that.

Answer (score 5):

Another reason for this error is if the property you are binding to is private.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possible reason for this (if you bind to an object) is that you try to bind to a field, not a property.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I just tripped over this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because the columns in both my tables had the same column names. For example:

1. My database name was `Assets`;
2. The first table name was `Property` and the second table name was `Plants`;
3. The first column names in both the tables were `asset_number`;
   It gave the error you describe above, but mine said `asset_number`.

Solution: I changed the column names in my table `Plants` to `asset_number1` and then it had no problem. (I did have to delete all my old columns in `Plants` to redo the new columns.)

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem where I have to change the name in the table but 
I haven't change column names in the data binding file. solution was changing the names by replacing the changed name.