# Why doesn't this custom binding source in my WinForms app work?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a custom binding source to store some app data in my WinForms app, instead of querying the UI for the data.

I have a simple class:

```
Public Class AppData
    Public companyFilterShowExpired As Boolean = True
End Class
```

I'd like to bind a checkbox in my GUI to this property. In my main form I have this code:

```
Private _appBindingSource = New BindingSource

Private Sub MainForm_Load...
    _appData.DataSource = New AppData()
    myCheckbox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _appData, "companyFilterShowExpired")
End Sub
```

When I run this I get an exception: `Cannot bind to the property or column companyFilterShowExpired on the DataSource. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645551/datasource-error-cannot-bind-to-property-or-column)?

Comment: I saw that, though his data source is a DataTable and mine is just a plain VB object.

Comment: just follow there suggestions/answer, the error state that column `companyFilterShowExpired` is not found in your `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a property, not a field:

```
Public Class AppData
  Public Property companyFilterShowExpired As Boolean = True
End Class
```

Comment: I see this doesn't do two-way binding, do you know how to accomplish that?

Comment: Your class probably needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  Which means you will probably have to break out your Property into Get...Set and raise the event in the Set method.