# Cannot bind to the property or column Ap_time on the DataSource

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I tried dragging a data source object from my Patients table into the form by expanding patients, going to appointments (it is there because it is connected with a foreign key) and dragging the appointment time onto the form.

When I run the program, I get "Cannot bind to the property or column Ap_time on the DataSource."

I am at a loss and am stressing out over this.

Heres my code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
public partial class PatientMaster : Form
{
    public PatientMaster()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ClassLibrary3.HospitalEntities dbcontext = new ClassLibrary3.HospitalEntities();

    private void PatientMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbcontext.Patients.OrderBy(patient => patient.Pat_Last_Name).ThenBy(patient =>      patient.Pat_First_Name).Load();

        patientBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.Patients.Local;
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `ToBindingList()`:

```
patientBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.Patients.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: See this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645551/datasource-error-cannot-bind-to-property-or-column