# "Cannot bind to the property or column Name on the DataSource" but column does exist

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-4.5, bindingsource

I have the following code that is supposed to implement data binding on two text boxes in my windows form:

```
private void GetData()
{
    bindingSourceStudies.DataSource = StudysTable;
    bindingSourceStudies.DataMember = "ID";

    txtName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSourceStudies, "Name"));  //#ERROR
    txtClass.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceStudies, "Class");
}
```

However, when I run it fails at the indicated line with the error message:

```
    Cannot bind to the property or column Name on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember
```

I am aware that there are many questions in this site about this particular error, however, most of them, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645551/datasource-error-cannot-bind-to-property-or-column) say that the named column is either not present or misspelled.  But as you can see below, the column called `"Name"` is clearly present in the BindingSource and appears to be spelled correctly.

[image]

I have tried it both with and without the `new Binding(...)` syntax, and it fails the same either way.  Clearly I am missing something, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what `.DataMember` is for on a BindingSource

- If you're binding a BindingSource to a DataTable, just set the `DataSource` e.g. `bindingSourceStudies.DataSource = StudysTable` and don't set the DataMember at all
- If you ever bind a BindingSource to a DataSet (a collection of DataTable), then set the `.DataSource = theDataSetVariableName` and also set the `.DataMember = "TheDataTableNameInsideTheDataSet"`.
- You might also set the `.DataMember` to the name of a `DataRelation` if you're displaying related data and have this BindingSource set to have its DataSource be another BindingSource

When  you bind a textbox, or whatever, you set the "ID" column binding in there when you set up the bindings:

```
txtName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSourceStudies, "ID", true));
                                                                   ^^^^
```

Bind multiple different textboxes to different columns on the same BindingSource

BindingSources maintain the notion of "current record" - all bound controls will change what they show, in sync, when the "current" item of their underlying bindingsource changes. If you use multiple bindingsources they will all maintain their own notion of "current"

---

Binding, the easy way:

- Add a new DataSet type file to your existing project
- Add tables to it, with columns, set their datatypes etc
- Switch to your form designer. Open Visual Studio's View menu, go *Other Windows*, then *Data Sources*
- Expand every node in it, and note that they all have dropdowns. Open a dropdown and have a look
- Drag any node onto the form. Voila, a (chosen type of control) appears, already bound to a bindingsource, already bound to a datatable withina  dataset. Drag more controls to bind to the same BS etc
- Add a datarelation between tables in the dataset. Expand more nodes in the DataSources window. Drag a node that is a child of another node, onto the form. Note the appearance of new bindingsource that is bound to a parent bindingsource. Now whenever the parent BS changes the data it is looking at, the child BS filters to show only members of its list that are children of the current parent

Comment: Ahhhh!  That's how BindingSource.DataMember works!  I was just translating from the [MS example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-navigate-data-with-the-windows-forms-bindingnavigator-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and it didn't register that it was the table name within the dataset.  Thanks!

Comment: No problems! I added another raft of info to the answer; if you didn't catch it, hit refresh and have another look

Comment: Funny, what they didn't tell you in the MS example, is that all those hundreds of lines of code were written by visual studio, not a human, using the "Binding, the easy way" I wrote about.. Make sure you don't waste your life plugging boilerplate like that, when a few clicks and drags can do it all

Comment: Yeah, a  ton of code and not much explanation as to what's going on and why.  The MS doc on databinding could be a whole lot better.

Comment: Mostly it comes as part of something else; like what I described with the "Make a dataset, add some tables, then drag the columns onto a form" process - the bigger overall goal is "download DB data into a dataset and show it on a form, update it, and save it" - a process that can be done entirely with mouseclicks, actually.. the data binding is a small cog part of that, that for the most part a human wou'dnt code by hand so it isn't documented to significant depth, i think

Comment: The thing is, I already have the datasources coming from one of my DLLs, I wanted to reuse them since everything else in the app uses them also.

Comment: Coming as a what? If it's a datatable, then you can fudge it with the visual approach by designing a dataset that is a mimic of what comes in, just the properties you need, then swap out the datasource on the bindingsource.. Or you can copy the code the designer wrote for you and re-paste it. DataSets can be based on objects but only if they have named properties. If your DataTables are base/generic ones then they don't have named props for stuff..

Comment: I can get them as anything, DataAdapter, DataSet, DataTable, etc.  I removed the `BindingSource.DataMember = "ID"` and the DataTable is working fine now.

Comment: If you get a dataadapter you can use it to fill the strongly typed dataset I describe in "Easy Way" - a DA just takes a base datatable and fills it; if the column names in the supplied datatable match then they will populate, it doesn't matter that you're supplying a strongly typed datatable to a datatadapter's Fill method (because a strongly typed DT is a derived subclass of a weakly typed DT that the DA needs) or a weakly typed one. Removing the datamember will get things working, but writing all this by hand is a very long and boring task that can be devolved to VS..